# What HTML is allowed in GitHub issues?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

[Along with Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics), GitHub allows "some HTML" when you compose issues, pull requests, and comments.

Is there a full list of exactly which HTML tags are allowed on GitHub? (similar to [*What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/205964))

Comment: what is the worth of putting html in git comments ?

Comment: @vaibhav I meant mainly for **GitHub** comments and issues; there are certain (and luckily, very few) things you cannot just do in Markdown, but need HTML to make right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Github has open sourced their text processing pipeline. The definition of the tag whitelist can be found in the [jch/html-pipeline](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/11cec3d43cab9f6beddd95bda40ad6ac654fe2f8/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb#L44-L95) repository.

At the time of writing, they allow the following tags along with common attributes (see the linked code for the exact details):

```
h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 h7 h8 br b i strong em a pre code img tt
div ins del sup sub p ol ul table thead tbody tfoot blockquote
dl dt dd kbd q samp var hr ruby rt rp li tr td th s strike
```